# Under the new Google Apps Marketplace OAuth 2 flow here do you register the call back URL?

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, google-apps-marketplace

When going through a server side flow with the new google apps marketplace oauth 2 I get a:

```
Error: redirect_uri_mismatch
The redirect URI in the request:http://localhost did not match a registered redirect URI
```

This used to be handled I believe in the manifest and I imagine could now be handled in the new manifest, but I don't see anything mentioned in the docs. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error indicates that your redirect_uri in request does not match the one you registered. You should go back to Google APIs Console to check the redirect_uri you registered.